# Android API 30 : How to install packages as App Self-Update

Tags: java, android, android-10.0

i found many threads about this topic but they are older than 5 years + and the used mechanics are currently not working anymore so i decided to re-open this question to get updated what the requirements to start successfully proceed an in App self update with the latest (Android 30) api.

My Preperations for this :

Used OS : Android API 30
Android Studio : latest
Repository : Nexus 3

I created a simple MainActivity as layout which contains a RelativLayout with one simple button that do onClick an AsyncTask (check update logic). This task proceed a simple rest request to my nexus 3 to get the latest version of my app. After a seconds click on the same button (just set a new listener after the first click finished) it will proceed the installation with following code :

```
public void installUpdate(String url,String fileName) {

    String destination = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/";
    destination += fileName;
    updateDestination = destination;
    final Uri uri_current = Uri.parse("file://" + destination);

    File file = new File(destination);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic simplebase64tokenherefornexus");
    request.setDescription("App Update");
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
    request.setTitle(fileName);
    request.setDestinationUri(uri_current);

    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);


    BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {

            if (!getPackageManager().canRequestPackageInstalls()) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES).setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s", getPackageName()))), 1234);
            } else {
                Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, "com.example.test.fileprovider", new File(file.getAbsolutePath(), fileName));
                Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                install.setDataAndType(uri, manager.getMimeTypeForDownloadedFile(downloadId));
                startActivity(install);
                unregisterReceiver(this);
            }
            finish();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}
```

Everything works fine, also the "install from unknown source" for my app is called correctly and activated. Both files (installed apk as release) and the update apk as release contains the same v1 + v2 signing key. The downloaded apk isn't corrupt, checked this with an manuell installation as update and it works fine, google play protect is disabled too.

In think i set the right permissions too , in my manifest i used the following permissions :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:testOnly="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.example.test.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_path" />
    </provider> ...
```

my provider_path :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="." />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

If i try it with current configuration i still get the "There was a problem parsing the package".

Did i miss something or did it wrong or are does anyone has a best practice example to get it work  ?

Answer (score 1):

for thoose who are running into the same issue :

found my issue, the failure was that i set the install permission to the wrong intent @ the broadcast xD